# What is Gazebo 9.0 equivalent of gazebo::physics::Joint->GetAngle() used in Gazebo 2.0?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-2.2, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In Gazebo 2.0, gazebo::physics::Joint->GetAngle() is used to Get the angle of rotation of an axis(index). This method is not available in Gazebo 9.0. I would like to know what is equivalent function in Gazebo 9.0

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19662/what-is-gazebo-9.0-equivalent-of-gazebo::physics::joint-%3Egetangle()-used-in-gazebo-2.0?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

According to the [migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo9/Migration.md?fileviewer=file-view-default#Migration.md-444):

```
***Deprecation:*** math::Angle GetAngle(unsigned int _index) const
***Replacement:*** virtual double Position(const unsigned int _index = 0) const final
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-06-11**:
Thanks. Are you aware of any implementation example of Position( ) function?

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-06-11**:
I was able to do it successfully in case any one has the same question. You have to call like:

`x = steering_joints[0]->Position(0);`

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-11**:
Glad you figured it out